# Trying to find elusive images

Tags: windows, windows-10, images, extract

I have an application that contains some images that I'd like in file form, however these images are not anywhere in any other related folders, neither does the application extract these images from external websites.

The images are also not in the appdata/local folder related to the developer of the application, the only things there consist of 3 configuration source files, which seem to only contain memory related to user settings.

I then tried using 7-Zip to see the insides, not relevant files there.
resourcehacker yielded about the same results as 7-Zip.

I don't know where the images may be stored, the only other files are dll files and an unrelated xml file, another unrelated .chs file, and text files that only list version information.

Please ask me questions or pose solutions to try, I'm up for anything.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways to get the images:

1. Images may be embedded in a file, such as .dll, .exe, or even other extensions. For example MSPaint uses mspaint.exe.mun for icons. Use a tool such as Angus Johnson's  [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/) to explore the images.

[image: mspaint.exe.mun in Resource Hacker]

2. Take a screenshot. If the applications prevents that, use a camera.

Comment: Unfortunately, all DLL files within contain the same formatting, Version Info, inside it, 1.0, which is just listing information about the version, there doesn't seem to be anything useful there.
[image](https://i.imgur.com/vsQVD8q.png)